# In android studio, what does this error message mean?

Tags: java

ParseError at [row,col]:[8,1]
Message: Element type "ImageView" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

In android studio, what does this error message mean? This was the layout file. I only have one layout:

```
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactCard2"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:text="George"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="353dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactCard3"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:text="Bill"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/contactCard2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dear Diary"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/contactCard1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactCard1"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
        android:text="Adrian"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/contactCard2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This looks like it's coming from a layout file. Can you show us the part containing the ImageView?

Comment: Ok, I now included the layout file in my question.

Comment: @AdrianKong there's no `ImageView` element in your layout. So you either posted the wrong layout or the wrong error message. Also, I guess that the missing `<` at the beginning of the file is just a copy-paste error.